# common pattern, Here so I am trying to simplify it to reduce duplication

Tags: c#

All of these if conditions in the below method have similar pattern,
Any ideas to come up with a common method to reduce the duplication in this method?

```
    public override Func<JObject, dynamic, string> version => (jobject, parameters) =>
    {
        bool hasValidObject = false;

        if (jobject["Version1"] != null)
        {
            _radio.Version1 = new VersionInfo(jobject["Version1"].Value<string>());
            hasValidObject = true;
        }

        if (jobject["Version2"] != null)
        {
            _radio.Version2 = new VersionInfo(jobject["Version2"].Value<string>());
            hasValidObject = true;
        }

        if (jobject["Version3"] != null)
        {
            _radio.Version3 = new VersionInfo(jobject["Version3"].Value<string>());
            hasValidObject = true;
        }

        if (jobject["Version4"] != null)
        {
            _radio.Version4 = new VersionInfo(jobject["Version4"].Value<string>());
            hasValidObject = true;
        }

        if (jobject["Version6"] != null)
        {
            _radio.Version6 = new VersionInfo(jobject["Version6"].Value<string>());
            hasValidObject = true;
        }

        if (hasValidObject)
        {
            return GenerateSuccess();
        }

        return GenerateUnsuccessful( try again.");
    };
```

Comment: Can you use one `Version` object in `_radio`? If so then you can have a for loop from 1 to 6 and use something like `jobject["Version"+i.ToString()]` to get/set those values. The alternative is to use reflection to get the property corresponding to your `i`.

Comment: each is different version like (hardware version,mobile version, tv version, etc.)

Comment: At least move version creation to another method, so that would be `_radio.Version1 = GetVersion(jObject, nameof(_radio.Version1));` Better avoid reflection for such a little gain (unless you have 100 versions, but then you should redesign class anyway).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another alternative can be with a `switch` statement:

```
public override Func<JObject, dynamic, string> version => (jobject, parameters) =>
{
    bool hasValidObject = false;

    foreach (char n in "12346")
    {
        var jObj = jobject["Version" + n];
        if (jObj != null)
        {
            var versionInfo = new VersionInfo(jObj.Value<string>());
            switch (n)
            {
                case '1': _radio.Version1 = versionInfo; break;
                case '2': _radio.Version2 = versionInfo; break;
                case '3': _radio.Version3 = versionInfo; break;
                case '4': _radio.Version4 = versionInfo; break;
                case '6': _radio.Version6 = versionInfo; break;
            }
            hasValidObject = true;
        }
    }

    return hasValidObject ? GenerateSuccess() : GenerateUnsuccessful(" try again.");
};
```

---

or a more advanced version with array of delegates .. because I like vertical space :] (also not tested):

```
public override Func<JObject, dynamic, string> version => (jobject, parameters) =>
{
    Func<VersionInfo, VersionInfo>[] a = { null, _radio.Version1 = v, 
                v => _radio.Version2 = v, v => _radio.Version3 = v,
                v => _radio.Version4 = v, null, v => _radio.Version6 = v };

    var q = from n in new[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 6 }
            let j = jobject["Version" + n] where j != null
            select a[n](new VersionInfo(j.Value<string>()));

    return q.Count() > 0 ? GenerateSuccess() : GenerateUnsuccessful(" try again.");
};
```

Answer (score 2):

One way is to use reflection and a loop

```
public override Func version => (jobject, parameters) => 
{ 
    bool hasValidObject = false;
    for (int i = 1; i<7;i++) 
    {
        hasValidObject = this.SetVersionInfo(i) || hasValidObject;
    }

    if (hasValidObject)
    {
        return GenerateSuccess();
    }

    return GenerateUnsuccessful( "try again.");
};


private bool SetVersionInfo(int i)
{
    if (jobject["Version" + i] == null) return false;

    _radio.GetType().GetProperty(propName)
        .SetValue(_radio, new VersionInfo(jobject["Version" + i].Value<string>()));
    return true;
}
```

Another way would be to create a `Dictionary<int,VersionInfo> Versions` in your `_radio` class and then a you don't need the reflection:

```
private bool SetVersionInfo(int i)
{
    if (jobject["Version" + i] == null) return false;

    _radio.Versions[i] = new VersionInfo(jobject["Version" + i].Value<string>());
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Unless the code requires dynamic access to properties by name, using reflection is overkill and could potentially cause performance issues.

Answer (score 0):

if *jobject* is of Dictionary type, you can run on it using

```
foreach(string version in jobject.keys)
{
     if(jobject[version]!=null){
     //do something
     }
}
```

the problem is with the radio, but if it your class, you can use an array of versions in the class instead of so many, and access to them with a counter that you will use to count the loop's number